# How can I controle React-Native webview in Detox?

Tags: react-native, detox

I can't find a way to control the React-Native Webview at https://github.com/wix/detox.

and There is another question,
Do you know how to press the Back button in React-Navigatoin?
[image]

If you give the correct answer, you are a nice guy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot interact RN webView with detox, platform limitations from iOS, Android.
Refer to these. 
https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/136#issuecomment-306591554
https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/334#issuecomment-335802212

To press Back button in iOS:

```
element(by.type('_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView')).tap();
```

To press Back button in Android:

```
device.pressBack()
```

I'm trying to be a nice guy

Comment: We've added support for web views for Android back in [Detox 18.7.0](https://github.com/wix/Detox/releases/tag/18.7.0). Support on iOS is in our roadmap.

Comment: @d4vidi any updates on when iOS webview support should be released? i cant find a public roadmap, is it still [planned for after v21](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/3030#issuecomment-1486906932)?

Comment: @benmneb Yes, it is planned for Detox 21. You can start using [the v21 RC](https://github.com/wix/Detox/releases/tag/21.0.0-rc.3) right now.

Answer (score 6):

A hackish solution our team implemented was to add a `Test` component along with our `WebView`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';


export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val:"",
    };
  }
  onPress() {
    const { webView } = this.props;
    if (webView && webView.executeJavascript) {
      webView.executeJavascript(this.state.val);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:0.1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <TextInput
          testID={"test_input"}
          onChangeText={val => this.setState({ val })}
          style={{flex:1,color:'white',backgroundColor:'#720000'}}
         />
         <TouchableOpacity
          testID={"submit_test_input"}
          onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}
          style={{flex:0.1,backgroundColor:'red'}}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Then from detox you can run arbitrary javascript like so:

```
await element(by.id('test_input')).replaceText(`
  $('#input-email').val('${USERNAME}');
  $('#input-password').val('${PASSWORD}');
  $('#login-form').submit();
`);
```

We have a custom webView that we use, so your solution would need to implement some sort of `executeJavascript` on your `WebView` as well.

Not the best solution, but works nonetheless.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to achieve something similar... could you provide more details about it? Where did you use this test component? Thanks

Comment: @ddacrs it's been a while since looking at this, but the test component would be rendered along with the webview during testing, all it does is add a place to inject JS (in this case JQuery) into the webview.