# Detox and React <-> WebView interaction

Tags: detox

I wonder if there is any plan to make Detox interact with React Webview. I have seen older articles like the one below in Mid 2018 where it was said to be out of scope. But since we're in 2019 close to Q2, just wanted to check if there are any new plans to implement this from Detox? That would be very beneficial for us given we are planning to use Detox for our cross platform UI automation for our React Native apps. There maybe a few hacks that could work like suggested below but there will be security concerns within the org in implementing such hacks.

[How can I controle React-Native webview in Detox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779998/how-can-i-controle-react-native-webview-in-detox)

Answer (score 1):

Detox supports both iOS and Android apps, so I'll separate the answers:

1. On iOS, Detox uses [EarlGrey](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey) to synchronize, match and perform actions. EarlGrey runs in-process, and was design for native UI hierarchy, such that has accessibility details. Moreover, web content on iOS is rendered inside a WKWebView, which runs [out-of-process](https://docs.kioskproapp.com/article/840-wkwebview-supported-features-known-issues#out-of-process), so technically this is not possible (and there are no plan to support it currently). This might be possible with XCUITest (and EarlGrey2, whenever it will be released).
2. On Android, [Espresso supports running on WebViews](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/web), but Detox does not export that functionality.